# User registration form Solspace integration

Tags: user-profile, registration

Is there any way to integrate Salesforce with Craft's [front-end user registration form](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form)? Is see [Freeform has a nice Salesforce integration](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/crm-api-salesforce/) but for this project the data needs to be sent across when people create a new member account, and when they update their profile.

Anyone tackled this before? Thanks!

Comment: You can create your own controller, copy the craft code of the `userController->actionSaveUser()` function to it and change the `action` value in the form to your controller. Then you add your custom logic to the method to call the API. That`s it.

Comment: Thanks Robin. Unfortunately this job has already been passed on to someone else, but good to know it's do-able if this comes up again.